# std::chrono gives abnormal value when I use cpulimit to limt the program

Tags: c++, cpu, clock, c++-chrono

My code is like:

```
while(1)
{
    std::cout << "local time " << std::chrono<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>((std::chrono::steady_clock::now()).time_since_epoch()).count() << "\n";
    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock();
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t3 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(), t4;
    
    MyProcessFunc();    
    
    t4 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    t2 = clock();
    std::cout << "process chrono time " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t4 - t3).count() << "ms\n";
    std::cout << "process clock time " << 1000.0*(t2 - t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "ms\n";
}
```

And when this program is running, I use "taskset" and "cpulimit" to restrict it to using only a single core of CPU and about 10% of this single core. Then I found chrono gives werid values:

```
local time 352398168
process chrono time 28ms
process clock time 26.829ms

local time 352398196
process chrono time 808ms
process clock time 26.934ms

local time 352399004
process chrono time 28ms
process clock time 27.168ms

local time 352399032
process chrono time 28ms
process clock time 27ms

local time 352399061
process chrono time 27ms
process clock time 26.931ms

local time 352399089
process chrono time 809ms
process clock time 30.479ms

local time 352399898
process chrono time 33ms
process clock time 32.135ms
```

I can feel the stutter of the program running, so may be chrono's result is right. But I think there are definitely other places that block the running of the program. The main part of the time consuming is not on my program.

Any one knows why plz

Comment: Can you make it run longer (for example 1 minute)? This should allow you to verify that the chrono time matches the real time.

Comment: It's hard to say unless we know for sure what is inside 'MyProcessFunc'. But with the CPU limiter on a busy loop (meaning your while loop does not seem to yield at all) I suspect that the CPU limiter is stopping the program as it spikes above 10% usage - this would /feel/ like stutter.

Comment: I kept running it and set CPU limit even to 5%, 1%, the chrono gives larger "break time" to 1000ms, and keeps same value to clock() at other loops. So I think JimmyNJ is right. 
 @vll

Answer (score 0):

`clock()` returns the time actually consumed by your program, [see here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/), while `std::chrono::steady_clock` keeps counting even when your program is not running.

This explains your results.